# update and insert queries creating a deadlock

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, deadlock

I will try to explain my problem as detailed as possible, and i would appreciate any help/suggestion. My problem is regarding a deadlock being caused by two queries (one insert and one update). I'm using MS-SQL server 2008

I have two applications using the same database:

1. Web app (on every request multiple records are inserted in the Impressions table by calling a stored procedure)
2. Windows service (calculates all the Impressions done in one minute, every minute, for the previous minute and sets a flag on each of the Impressions calculated via a stored procedure as well)

The web app inserts the impressions records without using a transaction, while the windows service application calculates the impressions while using a `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` transaction. The stored procedure in the windows service app does something like this:

**Windows Service stored procedure:**

Loops trough all the impressions that have the `isCalculated` flag set to false and date < @now , increments a counter and other data in another table connected to the impressions table, and sets the `isCalculated` flag to true on impressions that have date < @now. Because this stored procedure is pretty big, no point in pasting it, here is a shortened code snippet of what the proc does:

```
DECLARE @nowTime datetime = convert(datetime, @now, 21) 
DECLARE dailyCursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT  Daily.dailyId, 
        Daily.spentDaily, 
        Daily.impressionsCountCache ,
        SUM(Impressions.amountCharged) as sumCharged, 
        COUNT(Impressions.impressionId) as countImpressions
FROM    Daily INNER JOIN Impressions on Impressions.dailyId = Daily.dailyId
WHERE   Impressions.isCharged=0 AND Impressions.showTime < @nowTime AND Daily.isActive = 1
GROUP BY Daily.dailyId, Daily.spentDaily, Daily.impressionsCountCache

OPEN dailyCursor

DECLARE @dailyId int, 
        @spentDaily decimal(18,6), 
        @impressionsCountCache int, 
        @sumCharged decimal(18,6), 
        @countImpressions int

FETCH NEXT FROM dailyCursor INTO @dailyId,@spentDaily, @impressionsCountCache, @sumCharged, @countImpressions

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN   

        UPDATE Daily 
        SET spentDaily= @spentDaily + @sumCharged, 
            impressionsCountCache = @impressionsCountCache + @countImpressions
        WHERE dailyId = @dailyId

        FETCH NEXT FROM dailyCursor INTO @dailyId,@spentDaily, @impressionsCountCache, @sumCharged, @countImpressions
    END
CLOSE dailyCursor
DEALLOCATE dailyCursor

UPDATE Impressions 
SET isCharged=1 
WHERE showTime < @nowTime AND isCharged=0
```

**Web App Stored Procedure:**

This procedure is pretty simple it just inserts the record in the table. Here is a shortened code snippet:

```
INSERT INTO Impressions 
(dailyId, date, pageUrl,isCalculated) VALUES 
(@dailyId, @date, @pageUrl, 0)
```

**The Code**

The code that calls these stored procedures is pretty simple it just creates the SQL commands passing the needed parameters and executes them

```
//i send the date like this
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

SqlCommand comm = sql.StoredProcedureCommand("storedProcName", 
parameters, values);
```

I'm experiencing deadlocks very often (the exceptions occur in the web app, not the windows service), and after using the SQL-Profiler, I found out that the deadlocks are probably happening because of these two queries (I don't have much experience in analyzing profiler data).

The latest trace data collected from the SQL server profiler can be found on the bottom of this question

In theory these two stored procedures should be able to work together because the first one inserts the records one by one with date=DateTime.Now, and the second one calculates the Impressions that have date < DateTime.Now.

Edit:

Here is the code run in the windows service app:

```
SQL sql = new SQL();
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
//our custom DAL class that opens a connection
sql.StartTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
try
{
    List<string> properties = new List<string>() { "now" };
    List<string> values = new List<string>() { endTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) };
    SqlCommand comm = sql.StoredProcedureCommannd("ChargeImpressions", properties, values);
    comm.Transaction = sql.Transaction;
    ok = sql.CheckExecute(comm);
}
catch (Exception up)
{
    ok = false;
    throw up;
}
finally
{
    if (ok)
      sql.CommitTransaction();
    else
      sql.RollbackTransactions();
    CloseConn();
}
```

EDIT:

I added the indexes on both of the tables as suggested by Martin Smith like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Daily_DailyId] ON [dbo].[Daily] 
(
    [daily] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Impressions_isCharged_showTime] ON [dbo].[Impressions] 
(
    [isCharged] ASC,
    [showTime] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

For now no exceptions, will report back later

Edit:

Unfortunately this did not solve the deadlock issue. I will start a deadlock trace in profiler to see if the deadlocks are the same as before.

Edit:

Pasted the new trace (to me it looks the same as the previous one), couldn't capture a screen of the execution plan (its too big) but [here is the xml from the execution plan](http://pastebin.com/PjBfwuLc).And here is a screenshot of the execution plan of the insert query:

[image: execution plan of the insert query]

```
 <deadlock victim="process14e29e748">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process14e29e748" taskpriority="0" logused="952" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594045071360 (f473d6a70892)" waittime="4549" ownerId="2507482845" transactionname="INSERT" lasttranstarted="2011-09-05T11:59:16.587" XDES="0x15bef83b0" lockMode="S" schedulerid="1" kpid="2116" status="suspended" spid="65" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2011-09-05T11:59:16.587" lastbatchcompleted="2011-09-05T11:59:16.587" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"  hostpid="2200"  isolationlevel="snapshot (5)" xactid="2507482845" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="dbo.InsertImpression" line="27" stmtstart="2002" stmtend="2560" sqlhandle="0x03000600550e30512609e200529f00000100000000000000">
INSERT INTO Impressions 
    (dailyId, languageId, showTime, pageUrl, amountCharged, age, ipAddress, userAgent, portalId, isCharged,isCalculated) VALUES 
    (@dailyId, @languageId, @showTime, @pageUrl, @amountCharged, @age, @ip, @userAgent, @portalId, 0, 0)     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 6 Object Id = 1362103893]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process6c9dc8" taskpriority="0" logused="335684" waitresource="KEY: 6:72057594045464576 (5fcc21780b69)" waittime="4475" ownerId="2507482712" transactionname="transaction_name" lasttranstarted="2011-09-05T11:59:15.737" XDES="0x1772119b0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="3364" status="suspended" spid="88" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2011-09-05T11:59:15.737" lastbatchcompleted="2011-09-05T11:59:15.737" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider"  hostpid="1436" isolationlevel="read uncommitted (1)" xactid="2507482712" currentdb="6" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="dbo.ChargeImpressions" line="60" stmtstart="4906" stmtend="5178" sqlhandle="0x03000600e3c5474f0609e200529f00000100000000000000">
UPDATE Impressions 
    SET isCharged=1 
    WHERE showTime &amp;lt; @nowTime AND isCharged=0

    </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
Proc [Database Id = 6 Object Id = 1330103779]    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594045071360" dbid="6" objectname="dbo.Daily" indexname="PK_Daily" id="lock14c6aab00" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594045071360">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process6c9dc8" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process14e29e748" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594045464576" dbid="6" objectname="dbo.Impressions" indexname="IDX_Impressions_isCharged_showTime" id="lock14c901200" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594045464576">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process14e29e748" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process6c9dc8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
```

Edit:

After suggestions from Jonathan Dickinson:

1. I changed the stored procedure (removed the cursor),
2. I changed the IDX_Impressions_isCharged_showTime to not allow PAGE_LOCKS and
3. I added -1 second to the @now property in the windows service application to avoid borderline deadlock cases.

Update:

The query execution time was decreased after the last changes, but the number of exceptions hasn't.

Hopefully last update:

The changes proposed by Martin Smith are now live, the insert query now uses the non-clustered index and in theory this should fix the issue. For now no exceptions have been reported (Keeping my fingers crossed)

Comment: This article covers Read Uncommitted and locking behaviour: http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2008/08/28/sql-server-transaction-isolation-level-read-committed.aspx

Comment: The problem seems to be arising because of the FK relationship to `dbo.Daily` what indexes do you have on both tables?

Comment: I have a couple of indexes in both of the tables. Daily has two indexes (primary clutered "dailyId" and nonclustered non-unique "date"). Impressions has 3 indexes (primary clustered "impressionId", nonclustered non-unique "impressionId,dailyId,isCalculated,isCharged", and nonclustered non-unique "isCharged,portalId")

Comment: Also why does the windows service have an `X` lock on `dbo.Daily`? That isn't clear from the code you posted. Can you add that?

Comment: edited my question with the additional info

Comment: That isn't what I was asking for. Presumably the stored procedure you posted a snippet of is doing an insert, update, or delete of `dbo.Daily` at some point? Can you add the code for that? (+1 for `throw up;` though!)

Comment: pasted the full stored procedure

Comment: If the schema can be modified, have you considered using an [Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx) to support the `spentDaily` and `impressionsCountCache` columns. That way, SQL Server would perform the maintenance automatically, you'd have no code to write, and no deadlock...

Comment: The schema could be modified but an indexed view would not solve the problem because i have another stored procedure that deletes all the Impression records older than 3 days

Comment: Maybe you can try avoid using a cursor with an update on inner join, might be faster

Comment: Is there another part of your application that is performing a significant number of SELECTs on the Daily and/or Impressions tables?

Comment: There are a couple of select queries on the Daily and Impressions tables, but none of them appear in the deadlock trace results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your windows service cursor updates various rows in `Daily` for which it takes `X` locks. These won't be released until the transaction ends.

Your web app then does an Insert into `Impressions` and keeps an `X` lock on the newly inserted row whilst it waits for an `S` lock on one of the rows in `Daily` that are locked by the other process. It needs to read this to validate the FK constraint.

Your windows service then does the Update on `Impressions` taking `U` locks on the rows it scans along the way. There is no index that allows it to seek into the rows so this scan includes the row added by the web app.

So

(1) You could add a composite index to `Impressions` on `showTime, isCharged` or vice-versa (check the execution plans) to allow the rows that the windows service will update to be found by an index seek rather than a full scan.

-Or

(2) You could add a redundant non clustered index on `Daily(DailyId)`. This will be a lot narrower than the clustered one so the FK validation will likely use that in preference to needing an `S` lock on the clustered index row.

**Edit**

**Disclaimer: The following is based on supposition and observation rather than anything I have found documented!**

It seems that idea (2) does not work "as is". The execution plan shows that the FK validation still continues to happen against the clustered index regardless of the fact that a narrower index is now available. `sys.foreign_keys` has columns `referenced_object_id, key_index_id` and I speculate that the validation will currently always happen on the index listed there and the Query Optimiser doesn't currently consider alternatives but haven't found anything documenting this.

I found that the relevant values in  `sys.foreign_keys` and the query plan changed to start using the narrower index after I dropped and re-added the Foreign Key constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Daily(
    DailyId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  NOT NULL,
    Filler CHAR(4000) NULL,
) 

INSERT INTO Daily VALUES ('');


CREATE TABLE Impressions(
    ImpressionId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    DailyId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK REFERENCES Daily (DailyId), 
    Filler CHAR(4000) NULL,
)

/*Execution Plan uses clustered index - There is no NCI*/ 
INSERT INTO Impressions VALUES (1,1) 

ALTER TABLE Daily ADD CONSTRAINT
    UQ_Daily UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED(DailyId) 

/*Execution Plan still use clustered index even after NCI created*/    
INSERT INTO Impressions VALUES (1,1) 

ALTER TABLE Impressions DROP CONSTRAINT FK
ALTER TABLE Impressions  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK FOREIGN KEY(DailyId)
REFERENCES Daily (DailyId)    

/*Now Execution Plan now uses non clustered index*/    
INSERT INTO Impressions VALUES (1,1)
```

[image: Plan]

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution, your help and your time.I created the indexes and no exceptions for now. I will accept your answer if i don't receive any exceptions.

Comment: Unfortunately adding these indexes did not solve the issue (200 or so exceptions thrown throughout the weekend) :( I will get a trace running to see if there are any changes in the deadlocks

Comment: @Atzoya - Can you post one of the recent deadlock XML into the question? Also would be good to see the execution plans for the offending statements.

Comment: @Atzoya - I notice the `Insert` statements are different. Is this still being called by your web app as a single statement?

Comment: I left out some of the properties in my first post for brevity

Comment: Ah - OK. Would be good if you could look at the execution plans and confirm if they are using the new indexes or not. Ah - just spotted that the deadlocking `UPDATE` is filtering on `date>@now` rather than `showTime` so that other index wouldn't help unless this is another edit from you?

Comment: From the execution plans i can see that both the queries are using the PK_Daily index instead of the newly created one

Comment: Atzoya - Does `Daily` have any `insert` triggers on it that would use this index or is the `PK_Daily` index being used for the foreign key validation under an assert operator?

Comment: Daily doesn't have any triggers on it, and I don't get the part about foreign key validation under assert. I made a screenshot of the InsertImpressions execution plan and attached it to the question

Comment: RE: The assert operator I take it that will be off to the left of your screenshot. This is the operator that raises an error if a FK violation occurs. Having seen the plan I guess the problem is that for a single row insert SQL Server doesn't really care how narrow the index is as it only needs to validate 1 row.

Comment: @Atzoya - I like this answer. You might also want to try [ALLOW_TABLE_LOCKS=FALSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on your PK.

Comment: I saw the assert operator (it was off my screen duh), and under it's details I don't see anything regarding the PK_Daily index validation (only some nullchecks on 'Expr1014')

Comment: If it finds any non matching rows via the semi join then it will output `NULL` as the value for 'Expr1014' and this will raise an error. I'm now thinking that idea 2 was one that seemed good in principle but may not actually work in practice. So far I have not managed to get SQL Server to use anything other than the PK to validate the FK constraint so maybe it doesn't optimise this.

Comment: @Martin: Rebuilding the Table will be a bit complicated, but I will try it out on our test environment before going live. Because i cannot simulate the deadlock in the test system, is it safe to say that if the nonclustered index is used for the windows service app update query, the issue should be resolved?

Comment: @Atzoya - Well this is by no means an ideal solution as it relies on something completely undocumented that could change after a service pack upgrade for example but if you can prevent the insert from needing an `S` lock on the clustered index row itself by having it access the NCI then this deadlock should stop occurring. To be honest I still haven't taken a step back and looked at the overall process though to see if something can be changed there. I would definitely try and reproduce the deadlocks in your test environment so then you can verify if worth implementing.

Comment: I get it, at least I would know what to look for when rebuilding. Will try this out tomorrow and post the results (I need to plan this in a way that i don't lose data and with as little downtime as possible)

Comment: @Atzoya - Sorry you don't need to rebuild. I've found simply dropping and re-adding the foreign key does the job.

Comment: @Atzoya - Did you try dropping and recreating the FK? Is it now using the NCI? Is this now resolved?

Comment: Sorry i haven't responded ( Have been a bit under the weather some stomach flue or something ) But will try it out tomorrow and report the results

Comment: For now this solution looks good in my local environment (the insert uses the NCI), next step is test environment and if all is good I'm going live

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you again for your time and expertise. May a river of karma flow your way

Comment: Good stuff. Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 4):

Avoid cursors, that query had no need for them. SQL is **not** an imperative language (*which is why it gets a bad name because everyone uses it as one*) - it's a set language.

First thing you can do is speed up the basic execution of your SQL, less time parsing/executing the query means less chance of a deadlock:

- Prefix all your tables with `[dbo]` - this cuts up to 30% off the parse stage.
- Alias your tables - it cuts off a small amount off the planning stage.
- Quoting identifiers *may* speed things up.
- *These are tips from an ex-SQL-PM before anyone decides to dispute it.*

You can use a CTE to get the data to update and then use a `UPDATE ... FROM ... SELECT` statement to do the actual updates. This will be faster than a cursor, because cursors are **dog slow** when compared to clean set operations (even the fastest 'fire hose' cursor like yours). Less time spent updating means less of a chance of a deadlock. *Note: I don't have your original tables, I can't validate this - so check it against a development DB.*

```
DECLARE @nowTime datetime = convert(datetime, @now, 21);

WITH [DailyAggregates] AS
(
    SELECT  
        [D].[dailyId] AS [dailyId],
        [D].[spentDaily] AS [spentDaily],
        [D].[impressionsCountCache] AS [impressionsCountCache],
        SUM([I].[amountCharged]) as [sumCharged],
        COUNT([I].[impressionId]) as [countImpressions]
        FROM [dbo].[Daily] AS [D]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Impressions] AS [I]
               ON [I].[dailyId] = [D].[dailyId]
        WHERE [I].[isCharged] = 0
          AND [I].[showTime] < @nowTime 
          AND [D].[isActive] = 1
    GROUP BY [D].[dailyId], [D].[spentDaily], [D].[impressionsCountCache]
)
UPDATE [dbo].[Daily]
    SET [spentDaily] = [A].[spentDaily] + [A].[sumCharged],
        [impressionsCountCache] = [A].[impressonsCountCache] + [A].[countImpressions]
    FROM [Daily] AS [D]
    INNER JOIN [DailyAggregates] AS [A]
       ON [D].[dailyId] = [A].[dailyId];

UPDATE [dbo].[Impressions]
SET [isCharged] = 1 
WHERE [showTime] < @nowTime 
  AND [isCharged] = 0;
```

Furthermore you could disallow PAGE locks on your index, this will decrease the chances of a few rows locking a whole page (because of locking escalation, only a certain percentage of rows need to be locked before the entire page is just locked).

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_Impressions_isCharged_showTime] ON [dbo].[Impressions]              
(
    [showTime] ASC, -- I have a hunch that switching these around might have an effect.
    [isCharged] ASC  
)
WITH (ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)
ON [PRIMARY] 
GO
```

This will just mitigate the chances of a deadlock. You might try restricting @now a date in the past (i.e. `today - 1 day`) to make sure that the inserted row does not fall into the update predicate; chances are it will prevent the deadlock entirely.

Comment: +1 My next step was going to be to look at the overall process but seems you beat me to it!

Comment: I will try this out now, but i really don't know how much of an improvement this will be. The impressions table has about 400 000 records constantly, more or less, and i am experiencing 20 or so exceptions daily. I will also try and move back The DateTime.Now 1 second just in case

Comment: @Atzoya, any reason you get the date from the server? Why not use `GETDATE()` in SQL? If your servers' clocks are out of sync this could be causing issues.

Comment: I thought this too, I checked it out but it wasn't the case. I am declaring the DateTime in the application because i need it for some other operations (in the web app multiple impressions are inserted one by one with the same showDate). But removing one second from the DateTime.Now would solve any syncing issue

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the tips on speeding up query execution (I didn't know that cursors were slowing up the execution). I implemented them on our live system, and I am currently waiting for exceptions (fingers crossed)

Comment: @Atzoya - I've found a way to get it to use the narrow FK index if not.

Comment: @Martin I'm interested in your solution because if this system has bigger load than it currently has, the probability of deadlocks will increase. For now I've had 2 exceptions after the latest upload, so i don't think that this is the solution. It deffo speeds up execution but doesnt solve the deadlocks

Comment: @Atzoya - hopefully that's QAT! :) As I said, I wasn't able to test the outcomes of that query.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the changes the other answers suggest are called for since for example the use of a cursor is not necessary in your case... from the code you supplied there is even no need for the `WHILE` too...

I am no SQL Server guy... If I needed to do what your Stored Procedure is doing I would make sure that `@nowTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1)` and code it similar to the following:

```
BEGIN

UPDATE Daily D SET 
D.spentDaily= D.spentDaily + (SELECT SUM(I.amountCharged) FROM Impressions I WHERE I.isCharged=0 AND I.showTime < @nowTime AND I.DailyId = D.DailyId), 
D.impressionsCountCache = D.impressionsCountCache + (SELECT COUNT(I.impressionId) FROM Impressions I WHERE I.isCharged=0 AND I.showTime < @nowTime AND I.DailyId = D.DailyId)
WHERE D.DailyId IN (SELECT I.DailyId FROM Impressions I WHERE I.isCharged=0 AND I.showTime < @nowTime AND I.DailyId = D.DailyId) AND D.isActive = 1;

UPDATE Impressions I SET
I.isCharged=1 
WHERE I.showTime < @nowTime AND I.isCharged=0;

COMMIT;

END
```

Even with high load never had any deadlock trouble with any parallel `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` on `Impressions` this way (although that was Oracle)... HTH