Having a clustered primary key and a unique index on the same column?
Recently I added Blitz to look over some index data, it shows there's a duplicate clustered primary key and unique index in one of my tables. It's for a unique varchar (10) column.
Here are the definitions:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Products] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Products_1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([product_id])
-- Usage: Reads: 1,503,413 (464,967 seek 16,534 scan 1,021,912 lookup) Writes:1,016,923
-- Size: 47,155 rows; 96.5MB; 5.6MB LOB

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Products_1] 
    ON [dbo].[Products] ([product_id])
-- Reads: 1,663,103 (24,129 seek 1,638,974 scan) Writes:477
-- Size: 47,155 rows; 0.9MB

The 2nd non-clustered index is used in many foreign key constraints. But is there any point in keeping both of them? I'm not sure whether the usage/size means much here or what I should be looking at.
Should I replace the foreign keys to reference the clustered PK index instead and then drop the latter?

The PRIMARY KEY already enforces uniqueness - your unique index is not necessary

So I should drop every foreign key using the unique index, make it reference the clustered PK instead, and recreate the foreign keys? There's 30+ FKs referencing it which would be a pain ugh

per The Chesterton's fence principal do you understand why this situation came about in the first place? The narrower index might not be doing much harm as is only 0.9MB and getting very few writes and looks like it is scanned frequently (for which a narrower index can reduce the number of logical reads involved)

Should I replace the foreign keys to reference the clustered PK index instead and then drop the latter - thats definitely not something anyone not intimately familiar with your database can advise. But as per Martins comment, I would ask, what do you hope to gain from such a refactor? You have ~50K rows, so its a pretty small table - therefore unlikely to save you much space. Just document it somewhere and move on.

There is no need to create an index on every FK constraints. refer to : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/329051/is-indexing-foreign-keys-a-good-practice/436832#436832

Without knowing how wide the rest of your table is it's impossible to say. A narrower index can be very useful in some situations, which seems to be the case here. We'd need to see the full table definition along with any foreign key references.

@SQLpro I beg to differ with your answer there. Yes, it's usually better to make it a multi-column index, and if you already have a PK on it then no point adding it. But if you don't have any index at all (with the FK columnset as the leading key) then you will get huge scans every time you do a delete on the parent table.

That is not at all relevant to the question asked here anyway. Nowhere are they asking about indexing on the referencing column.

Apart from logical reads for scans that only require the ProductId one other reason why this logically redundant index could have been added could have been to address a deadlock issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283500/update-and-insert-queries-creating-a-deadlock/7285041#7285041
